# jquery checking if the selected element is the current of each member

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many select options lists `<select>` and on change of one of them I want to apply some action to the others except the current one i.e the active list that triggered `change` event. I follow code like the following:

```
<select class="ops">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="1">One</otption>
  <option value="2">Two</otption>
  <option value="3">Three</otption>
  <option value="4">Four</otption>
</select>
<select class="ops">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="1">One</otption>
  <option value="2">Two</otption>
  <option value="3">Three</otption>
  <option value="4">Four</otption>
</select>
<select class="ops">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="1">One</otption>
  <option value="2">Two</otption>
  <option value="3">Three</otption>
  <option value="4">Four</otption>
</select>
<select class="ops">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="1">One</otption>
  <option value="2">Two</otption>
  <option value="3">Three</otption>
  <option value="4">Four</otption>
</select>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var basicObj;
  $("select.ops").change(function(){
    basicObj = $(this);
    $("select.ops").each(function(){
      if ($(this) !== basicObj){
       // do something
       $(this).css('color','red');
      }
    })

 })
})
</script>
```

The problem here is `if ($(this) !== basicObj)` always evaluated as true so, for example, when the first select list changed, its color changed to red too! [**this code demo**](http://jsbin.com/wekurexewe/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason why  not working  :**

Note that jQuery selectors return the Jquery collection of selected objects,  mean that they never be equal in the sense of reference equality.

To compare Jquery objects, [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function

> Description: Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

To check jquery objects equals you should have tried `!$(this).is(basicObj)`

```
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("select").change(function(){
        var basicObj = $(this);
        $("select").each(function(sel){
          debugger;
          if (!$(this).is(basicObj)){
           // do something
           $(this).css('color','red');
          }
        })

     })
    })
    </script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/dubatujike/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: It works fine now, however, I need to understand,  `$(this)` is an object of the current element, is not it? so why it is not equals to its referenced `basicObj`?

Comment: I just need to understand the concept behind it. Always I understand that `$(this)` for any element means or equals its object.

Comment: So, do you mean that in this case and inside `each` `$(this)` is regarded as an array element not an object?!

Comment: @SaidbakR not literally array, it is Jquery collection of objects.

Comment: Well, a collection of objects but inside `each` function we deals with one object only not the whole of the collection!